# When installing Moodle 2.8 on Windows 7, at moodle/user/editadvanced.php goes to a blank page

Tags: windows, installation, moodle

I'm trying to install moodle 2.8 on Windows 7, locally, and the installation goes to a blank page after editing the admin user profile. It links: localhost/moodle/user/editadvanced.php and it just a blank page.

What can I do to solve this? I've seen installation tutorials on youtube, but they don't have to deal with this.

Also, I've already tried using XAMPP 3.2 and WampServer.

Answer (score 0):

Moodle 2.8 requires PHP 5.4.4 or later. Please confirm you are using the correct PHP version.